# Calling a function which is inside a Thread

Tags: c++, pthreads, googletest, gcov, lcov

I was doing Unit Testing and finding code coverage using gtest and lcov.
My function is

```
void MyClass::MyFunction(const std::string& argument1, const std::string& argument2) {
    std::thread([this, argument1, argument2]() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> live_lock_(live_mutex_);
        int64_t time_stamp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        int64_t time_to_live = myList[argument1] - (time_stamp % myList[argument1]); 
        cond_var_.wait_for(time_to_live_lock_, std::chrono::milliseconds(time_to_live), [this, argument1] { return cond_var_status_[argument1]; });
        if (message_master_.find(argument1) != message_master_.end()) {
            //something
        }
    }).detach();
    std::cout<< "end line is executed"<<std::endl; }
```

and my test function is

```
TEST(test, test1) {
    Myclass testObj;
    testObj.MyFunction("arg1", "arg2");
    ASSERT_EQ("","");
};
```

When I run the test, all codes except those inside thread are executed.
So is there any solution to call those codes inside thread too?

Comment: I doubt it, since you have gone out of your way to create a thread and detach it, so its execution continues independently of the calling thread - without keeping any reference to the `std::thread` object that manages the thread.   Which means that the calling thread immediately relinquishes control.   Unless the thread does "something" with external observable effects, and your test case explicitly finds a way to wait on the thread and check if observable effects have occurred, there is no solution.   You need to design for both multithreading and testability, not just for multithreading.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes, `cond_var_` is `std::condition_variable`

Comment: If you can't test results of thread execution externally, then why bother with multithreading? Just test whatever in this thread happens in separate test, instead of separate thread. PS: If you need to test inter-thread synchronization, then write correct tests.

Comment: The function `TEST(test, test1)` will likely return long before the code in the thread has executed. `testObj` will be destroyed and all the variables it owns with it, makeing the code in the thread using a dangling `this` pointer so, undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know none of those lines are being executed?
I would suggest making a test program, compiling with -g and -Wall, then using gdb to make sure a thread is actually being created. If it is, step through the code.
It could be that the compiler gets rid of code it thinks is doing nothing.

Comment: i checked the code coverage using lcov, that's how i found which all lines are executed.
i'm using cmake to build the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would test it (I modified the code a little, but in principle it is the same thing. All the globals shall be moved to `MyClass` most probably):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex time_to_live_mutex_;
std::map<std::string, int64_t> myList;
std::map<std::string, bool> cond_var_status_;
std::map<std::string, std::string> incoming_message_master_;
std::condition_variable cond_var_;
std::atomic_bool something_happened{false};


void foo(const std::string& argument1, const std::string& argument2) {
    std::thread([argument1, argument2]() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> time_to_live_lock_(time_to_live_mutex_);
        int64_t time_stamp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        int64_t time_to_live = myList[argument1] - (time_stamp % myList[argument1]); 
        cond_var_.wait_for(time_to_live_lock_, std::chrono::milliseconds(time_to_live), [argument1] { return cond_var_status_[argument1]; });
        if (incoming_message_master_.find(argument1) != incoming_message_master_.end()) {
            //something
            something_happened = true;
        }
    }).detach();
}

TEST(TestFoo, testing_foo_thread) {
  int64_t timeout = 10000;
  myList["bar"] = timeout; // so that cond variable waits long time
  cond_var_status_["bar"] = false; // so that cond variable returns false at first try
  incoming_message_master_["bar"] = std::string("42"); // so that something can happen
  foo("bar", "fiz");

  ASSERT_FALSE(something_happened); // cond variable is still waiting at this point

  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> time_to_live_lock_(time_to_live_mutex_);
    cond_var_status_["bar"] = true; // so that cond variable returns eventually
  }

  while(!something_happened && timeout > 0) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    timeout -= 10;
  }

  ASSERT_TRUE(something_happened); // cond variable is not waiting, should have returned
}
```